# Tensorflow: sess.run() for prediction does not change values

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I am new to tf and I am working on an image classifier. I have built the model. I use `sess.run()` to predict a single image from the model learnt but no matter what the input is, the output labels are not changed.

```
def predict():

tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.Session() as sess:

    new_saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('~/trained-model.ckpt.meta')
    new_saver.restore(sess, '~/trained-model.ckpt')

    y_pred = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('y_pred:0') #softmax(output_of_last_layer) is equal to y_pred
    X = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('X:0')
    final = imageprepare('jean.jpeg')
    final = np.asarray(final) 

    print(type(final))
    final = np.reshape(final,[784,1])
    print (type(final))

    output_label = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={X: final}) 
    print(output_label)
```

No matter what the input is, the `output_label` values remain the same which is  np array of shape [number_of_lables,1]

I trained a model and saved it. I am trying out different input images now to see what class they belong to. If I change any input image, it should change the output_label as the output_label contains the probability of how close the answer is But output_label is not depending on the input image which is the problem Any solutions for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The whole code is on codeshare.io/2jO4oR

Comment: Have you checked the weights, are they zero everywhere?

Comment: @ArpitKathuria No, nowhere. I tried predicting one image after training the model (without saving and then reloading). The `output_labels` are all ones

Answer (score 0):

There is no function to modify the values of `output_label`

To fix that:

```
img1 = imageprepare('x.jpeg')
img1 = np.asarray(img1)
img2 = imageprepare('y.jpeg')
img2 = np.asarray(img2) 
img3 = imageprepare('z.jpeg')
img3 = np.asarray(img3) 

input_images = [img1,img2,img3]    
output_label = sess.run(y_pred, feed_dict={X: input_images})
```

where x,y,z are input images

Comment: but if I change the input image which is `final`, it should change the values of `output_label`. Shouldn't it?

Comment: I ran it multiple times. I changed it manually and the values are exactly the same.

Comment: It's not what I am asking. If I change the input image, the values of output_label remains same which is wrong. It shows the probability of how close an image is to a label(or class) but if I input two images, the values are same.

Comment: I trained a model and saved it. I am trying out different input images now to see what class they belong to.
If I change any input image, it should change the output_label as the output_label contains the probability of how close the answer is
But output_label is not depending on the input image which is the problem
Any solutions for this?